# Error in my random 32 bit generation

Tags: c

I want to generate 32 bit random number using the following C code. For small 'LOOP', it works well. But for larger LOOP>1024*1024*4, all final value becomes 1/32. Can you kindly explain where is problem in the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

#define ul unsigned int
#define ull unsigned long long 



ul myrand32(){

        ul temp=4294967296.0*drand48();

        return temp;

}

int main(){

ul temp;
ull i,j,s,Z, LOOP=1024*1024*1024;
double A[32];
srand(time(NULL));
srand48(time(NULL));

for(i=0;i<32;i++)
   A[i]=0;

for(i=0;i<LOOP;i++){
                    temp=myrand32();      

                    j=temp%32;
                    A[j]+=1;


               }

for(j=0;j<32;j++)
    printf("%lf   %llu   %lf\n", A[j]/i,j,1.0/32);

}
```

Comment: I think it is precision - the multiply by 2^32 ensures all the bits of accuracy are moved into the top of the number, then the value is truncated to 32, leaving only 5 bits of information, from the lower end of the accuracy of the double.   Try multiplying by 0x10000 =>  65536 instead of 0x100000000.

Comment: or use `int n32bit = rand() | (rand() << 16)`

Comment: use uint32_t when you want a integer with 32 bit. not int, long or something like that, even it is 32 bit on your plattform. On other platform, int and long will have a different size.

Comment: Don't create macros for types, that's what `typedef` is for. And don't create macros with reserved names. `ul` is a built-in suffix for for `unsigned long` integer literals, `ull` is the same for `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So drand48 uses 48 bits of randmonness.  This generates a number between 0 and 1 as follows in binary floating point.

```
0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
and
0.111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

(not quite 1, but with 48 '1's.)

when multiplied by 4billion, that turns into

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
to
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000
```

When truncated to 5 bits, that is

```
00000
00000
```

Multiply by the range required... e.g. 32, rather than a large number.

Comment: What is "bicimal"?